# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 18; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'properties'

Tags: jpa, xml-validation, persistence.xml

I did following tutorial [link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xAJcA8adDE)

and I am getting

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 18; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'properties'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":property}' is expected.

which is pointing to my presistence.xml which looks as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="loginTestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <class>entities.User</class>
  <properties>   
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/p?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="User"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="p"/>
    <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

What kind of property is expected?

Also on video the Eclipse_JPA library was used, I have netbeans 8.1 installed and it doest have this library I have used EclipseLink(JPA2.1) instead. This is only difference between my implementation and this one on video.

Comment: Use `</properties>` in place of `<properties/>'

Comment: Ok now I am getting different error which is ok right now the'<properties/>' was auto generated by netbeans what is a difference with forward slash before or after properties?

Comment: `<properties/>` is nothing but a short of `<properties/> <properties/>` But if you want to add something between `<properties/> <properties/>`  which you done in your case you cannot use `<properties/>`

Comment: ok i can accept your answer for this quetion Subodh Joshi just make an answer. thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `</properties>` in place of `<properties/>`

`<properties/>` is nothing but a short of `<properties/> <properties/>` But if you want to add something between `<properties/> <properties/>` which you trying to do in your case you cannot use `<properties/>`